# Wirelessly transmit computer screen to TV?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, tv

We've got about 7 Ubuntu-based machines which we want to be able to display on a TV screen at will (but only one at a given time). What's the best way to do that?

We haven't bought the TV yet, if there's one that makes this easier.

We want to project IDEs, websites, and other apps, so video-streaming-only devices won't work.

It would be preferable to be able to stream over our wifi network (through a router) to the TV, rather than needing 7+ transmitters.

Is there such a thing that can do this?

Comment: WiDi seems like the technology you're looking for (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiDi), but I don't know if Ubuntu supports it.

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned a budget, but the wePresent device can probably do this, although it is fairly expensive. There is no supported driver for Linux but this person reports that it works fine with Wine:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1564798

Comment: I don't have a hard budget; it's for our office. A few hundred dollars is OK if it's the best solution. We're not very big fans of Wine here but thank you for the suggestion.